# Why is it possible to use more than 2 ^ 16 constants in a Python function?

Tags: python, python-internals

In internal modules like [peephole](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Python/peephole.c), argument of `LOAD_CONST` is stored in the two bytes following the `opcode`.

For example, the macro it uses to get argument of an operation is implemented as:

`#define GETARG(arr, i) ((int)((arr[i+2]<<8) + arr[i+1]))`

The argument of `LOAD_CONST` is an index into the `consts` array.

So I guessed maybe we can only use at most 2 ^ 16 constants in a Python function.

But when I experiment with a function that use 66666 (> 65536) constants, it still runs normally.

What could be the reason?

Comment: How did you build the function? Check `f.__code__.co_consts` and see if there are actuall 66666 constants there. Maybe they got optimized out.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, I've confirmed that they are still there.

Comment: I built such a function and decompiled it with `dis.dis`. Looks like there's an `EXTENDED_ARG` opcode that handles it.

Comment: @user2357112 ;) I also found out this operation, googling for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-EXTENDED_ARG) docs:

> EXTENDED_ARG(ext)
>
> Prefixes any opcode which has an argument too big to
> fit into the default two bytes. ext holds two additional bytes which,
> taken together with the subsequent opcode’s argument, comprise a
> four-byte argument, ext being the two most-significant bytes.

If an opcode needs an argument longer than 2 bytes, an EXTENDED_ARG opcode provides 2 more bytes of argument.

Comment: +1.. By the way has everyone ever heard of a function that takes more than 2^16 parameters? Or even close to that?

Comment: @Ant This should be a very rare case.